# How to (mock) test external API request that happens inside Next.js getStaticProps

Tags: testing, next.js, cypress

I'm using cypress to test my Next.js build.

As the point of `getStaticProps`, a query is made to an external API and the data returned is formatted and then passed as props to the component.

I know `getStaticProps` happens at build time / revalidation time so this makes it difficult to test at the component level (as the query has already been completed).

Does anyone know the best approach here?
Can I pass fake props to the component somehow? And then test the component with cypress?

Comment: Potentially related question: [Cypress with NextJS SSR - intercept RESTful API using Axios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67615470/cypress-with-nextjs-ssr-intercept-restful-api-using-axios).