# Mocking / intercepting an API for Cypress e2e in Next 14 App Router?

Tags: next.js, cypress, server-side-rendering

I'm trying to establish a clean way of setting up mocking/interception for a REST API so I can return fixtures during e2e testing.

I initially experimented with `cy.intercept` but quickly discovered that this doesn't work with components that are rendered on the server because `intercept` is only aware of requests that happen in the client. The practical upshot of which is that the `cy.intercept` is never triggered.

My next attempt followed [this suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70620363/424150) of using [MSW](https://mswjs.io/) to mock the endpoints independently, which would be unaffected by whether the API request was coming from the server or the client. However, [this discussion](https://github.com/mswjs/msw/issues/1644) suggests this is a non-starter due to lack of App Router support. That discussion suggests using [Playwright](https://playwright.dev/) or using [http-middleware](https://github.com/mswjs/http-middleware) to run MSW as a self contained server.

Am I missing something here? It feels that, by choosing Cypress for e2e tests, I've backed myself well and truly into a corner. It feels like there must be a simple solution for this that I've not found!

If anyone has any suggestions, I'll be very grateful!